# Number of steps in a nested loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to calculate the number of steps executed for the following nested loop specially for asymptotic growth. Based on the number of steps I will derive the Big O for this algorithm.

```
def get_multiples(list):
    multiple = []
    for o in list:
        for i in list:
            multiple.append(o*i)
    return multiple
```

The way I have calculated is as follows (list consists of large number of elements = "n"):

1. Assignment statement (no. of steps = **1**):

   ```
   multiple = []
   ```
2. Nested Loops:

   ```
   for o in list:
      for i in list:
          multiple.append(o*i)
   ```

   In the outer loop the variable o is assigned n times. Each time the outer loop executes, first the variable i is assigned n times, then the variables are multiplied n times and finally the list is appended n times. Therefore the no. of steps = **n*(n+n+n)** = **3n<sup>2</sup>**
3. Return statement (No. of steps = **1**):

   ```
   return multiple
   ```

Therefore the total no. of steps = **3n<sup>2</sup> + 2**

However the correct answer is **3n<sup>2</sup> + n +2**. Apparently the execution of the outer loop takes additional **n** steps which is not required for the inner loop.

Can somebody explain to me what did I miss ?

It does not make a difference to complexity since it will still be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

Comment: You wrote it yourself: "In the outer loop the variable o is assigned n times".

Comment: @n.m The way the answer should be is as follows: 1 + n*(3*n +1). The outer loop variable assignment will happen every time the loop executes therefore it is the multiplier n in the result. My question is why do we still have to consider the extra 1 step each time the outer loop executes i.e. the "n*(...+1) part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the correct way to calculate  the nested loop is as follows:

The number `o` is assigned n times.
the number `i` is assigned n<sup>2</sup> times, o*i is calculated n<sup>2</sup> times, the append function is called n<sup>2</sup> times.

therefore n + n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> = 3n<sup>2</sup> + n

add it to the rest and you get 3n<sup>2</sup> + n + 2

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_multiples(list):  
  multiple = []  // 1 STEP  
  for o in list:  // Executed n times, so n STEPS  
    for i in list: // Executed n times for each value of o, so n*n STEPS  
      multiple.append(o*i) // 1 STEP to multiply and 1 STEP to append, repeated for each pair of (o, i), so 2*n*n STEPS  
  return multiple // 1 STEP
```

Adding the above: **1 + n + n<sup>2</sup> + 2n<sup>2</sup> + 1 = 3n<sup>2</sup> + n + 2**